# How to DensityPlot3D the solution of a PDE?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, finite-element-method

I solve a Dirichlet problem on a parallelepiped in 3D

```
p = Parallelepiped[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}];
sol = NDSolve[{Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 0, 
DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == x^4 + y^2 + z, True]}, u[x, y, z], {x, y, z} \[Element] p]
```

> `{{u[x,y,z]->InterpolatingFunction[Domain: {{0.,2.},{0.,2.},{0.,1.}} Output: scalar][x,y,z]}}`

I'd like to vizualize that solution. Following [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot3D.html) (see the Applications section),
I try

```
DensityPlot3D[ u[x, y, z] /. sol, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

The above command works, but produces an empty plot without any error messages.
My next attempt is

```
Clear[x,y,z,u];DensityPlot3D[Evaluate[u[x, y, z] /. sol], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

with an unsatisfactory result as well as

```
Clear[x,y,z,u];DensityPlot3D[Evaluate[u[x, y, z] /. sol], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 12]
```

[image]

The slices of `sol` are plotted well, for example,

```
Plot3D[(u[x, y, z] /. sol) /. z -> 0.2, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Clear[x, y, z, u]; sol1 =   NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 0,     DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == x^4 + y^2 + z, True]},    u[x, y, z], {x, y, z} \[Element] p];DensityPlot3D[u[x, y,z] /. sol1, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 1}] ` also produces an empty plot.

Comment: this is because you should use `NDSolve` here  if you want to use it a as rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work?

```
Clear[x, y, z, u,p,U];
p = Parallelepiped[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}];
U = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == x^4 + y^2 + z, True]}, 
   u, {x, y, z} \[Element] p];
```

Then

```
U[x, y, z] // Evaluate, {x, y, 
  z} \[Element] p, Contours -> 5, MeshFunctions -> (Norm[{#1, #2, \
#3}] &)]
```

[image]

---

**Update**

As requested by OP, you can find the range of values via:

```
   NMaximize[U[x, y, z], {x, y, z} \[Element] p] // Quiet
```

{12.713,{x->1.80957,y->1.28142,z->0.30654}}

```
   NMinimize[U[x, y, z], {x, y, z} \[Element] p] // Quiet
```

{1.07235,{x->0.996752,y->0.101257,z->0.0664789}}

So that

```
  ContourPlot3D[U[x, y, z] // Evaluate, {x, y, z} \[Element] p, 
 Contours -> (val = {1,2,5}), 
 MeshFunctions -> (Norm[{#1, #2, #3}] &), 
 ContourStyle -> ColorData["Heat"] /@ (Range[5]/5.), 
 PlotLegends -> val]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. You first plot is a duplication of my first plot. Which surfaces are drawn in your second plot? Can you demonstrate more such surfaces? The behavior of the solution near the origin is not clear to me. Unfortunately, I cannot accept your answer in its present form.

Comment: +1. However, there are still deficiences: some surfaces are partly out of `p` and the levels of `U` are not known.

Comment: `ContourPlot3D[U[x, y, z] // Evaluate, {x, y, z} \[Element] p, 
 Contours -> {1, 2, 5}]` suits better to me. I'll be wating some time for other answers (maybe, through `ListDensityPlot3D`).